# GET http://localhost:8080/pacific/admin/purchase/imgname.png 404 (Not Found) problem in ajax ,html ,php

Tags: php, html, ajax

**View:**

```
<li id="imgid0">
</li>
```

**Append Part:**

```
$("<img width='50' height='50'>").attr( "src", hc.photo ).appendTo("#imgid0");
```

and getting this error:

> GET 
>   http://localhost:8080/pacific/admin/purchase/imgname.png 404 (Not
>   Found)

NOTE: "imgname.png" is uploaded in 'pacific/uploads/' folder.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The value of `hc.photo` is `/pacific/admin/purchase/imgname.png` (or something similar), and yet you said the image exists in `pacific/uploads/` - these are two different locations, that's why you have a 404.

Comment: this /pacific/admin/purchase/imgname.png  value  is default , but I want to change that to /pacific/uploads/imgname.png @Jonathan

Comment: How is this related to PHP or Ajax?

Comment: I'm  using Codeigniter and this append part is written in Ajax . So thats how it is related to Ajax and Php i think . @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Then you need to show us _all_ the relevant code. Currently, the code you show uses neither PHP or Ajax. A quick solution though would probably be: `.attr('src', hc.photo.replace('/pacific/admin/purchase/', '/pacific/uploads/').appendTo(...);`

Comment: I think you should rewrite the directory of images with .htaccess

Comment: Simply change value of `hc.photo` to have proper path. Maybe you provide just relative path `imgname.png` instead of absolute `/pacific/uploads/imgname.png`?